# CONCATENATEX in multi-row card (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have the sample data below

[image]

I used the code below to get the result as below for measure.

CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table[Type]),Table[Type],", ")

It worked for the table view. However, when I do the count in multi-row card, it won't work.
[image]

My desired outcome is something looks like below. Looking to have the view in Multi-row card to get the outcome like that. Please help!!! Either measure or column will be fine as long as it gives me the result.

[image]

Comment: what are you counting and how?

Comment: I'm counting base on ID + last + first name because sometime they have different ID but same name. This will give me the unique type.

Comment: Then I just look at column name "Type" to count for how many types.

Comment: unfortunately, the measure that I used didn't work on the count and it can only view in table.

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, you need a calculated column first

```
Column = CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Table'[type]),'Table'[type],","), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[id]))
```

Then you can create a measure to show the count

```
Measure =
COUNTX ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[id], 'Table'[Column] ), [Column] )
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Can you please explain where do you get [try], [Measure] and [ct]?

Comment: Also, CURRENTGROUP(). Thank you!